# How to get table values in jquery which is iterated using thymeleaf th:each?

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Here i created a simple table,that has list of enity type object, which is itreated by thmeleaf th:each,i have a struggle to fetch the data from the table,,Here is the codes

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 
 var formData;
 var url = window.location;
 // SUBMIT FORM
    $("#submit").click(function(event) {
  // Prevent the form from submitting via the browser.
  event.preventDefault();
  
  var rowcount =  $("#manualtable td").closest("tr").length;
  var wrpmanualbillentry=[]; //array variable
  var rc;
  
  var mbeid = $("input[name='mbeid[]']");
  var watercharge = $("input[name='watercharge[]']");
  
  for(rc=0;rc<rowcount;rc++)
  {
     
  wrpmanualbillentry.push({
       
        flatid : $("input[name=mbeid[]]").val(),
        watercharge :$("input[name=watercharge[]]").val(),
        waterchargeconsumed : $("input[name=waterchargeconsumed[]]").val(),
        powercharge : $("input[name=powercharge[]]").val(),
        powerchargeconsumed : $("input[name=powerchargeconsumed[]]").val()
           })
  }
  
      alert(wrpmanualbillentry);
      console.log(wrpmanualbillentry);
  
  //sample exercise
  
  /*var TableData = new Array();
    $('#manualtable tr').each(function(row, tr) 
  {
      TableData[row] = {
        
        "flatid": $(tr).find('input:eq(0)').val(),
        "flatname": $(tr).find('input:eq(1)').text(),
        "powercharge": $(tr).find('input:eq(4)').val(),
        "powerchargeconsumed": $(tr).find('input:eq(5)').val(),
        "watercharge": $(tr).find('input:eq(2)').val(),
        "waterchargeconsumed": $(tr).find('input:eq(3)').val()
        
      }//tableData[row]
    });
    
    TableData.shift(); // first row will be empty - so remove
    alert(TableData);
    console.log(TableData);*/
  

    
  // PREPARE FORM DATA
     var formData = wrpmanualbillentry;         
     alert(JSON.stringify(formData));
     
     // DO POST
     $.ajax({
   type : "post",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   url : url+"/manualbill",
   dataType : "json",
   data : JSON.stringify(formData),
   success : function(result) 
   {
    if(result.status == "saved")
    {
     $("#resultid").html(" Bill Details saved Successfully!" );
    }
    else
    {
     $("#resultid").html("<strong>Error</strong>");
    }
    
    /*alert(result.dataObj.username);*/
    console.log(result);
    console.log(result.status);
   },
   error : function(e) {
    
    $("#resultid").html("<strong>Error</strong>");
    /*$("#resultid").html(" Bill Details saved Successfully!" );*/
    console.log("ERROR: ", e);
   }
  });
     
     // Reset FormData after Posting
     resetData();
 });
    function resetData()
    {
   $("#waterchargeconsumed").val(""),
   $("#powerchargeconsumed").val("")
   
    }
});
```

```html
<table id="manualtable">   
      <thead class="thead-default">  
        <tr>  
          <th>Flat ID</th>  
          <th>Flat Name</th>  
          <th>Name of the Charge</th>  
          <th>Unit Consumed</th>  
          <th>Name of the Charge</th>
          <th>Unit Consumed</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>  

      <tbody>  
        <tr th:each="mbe : ${manualbillentry}">  
          <td><input type="text" id="mbeid" th:value="${mbe.pkflatid}" style="border-color: transparent; border: none;" readonly/></td> 
          <td th:text="${mbe.flatname}"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="watercharge" name="watercharge" style="border-color: transparent; border: none;" value="Water Charge" readonly="readonly" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="waterchargeconsumed" name="waterchargeconsumed" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="powercharge" name="powercharge" style="border-color: transparent; border: none;" value="Power Charge" readonly="readonly" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="powerchargeconsumed" name="powerchargeconsumed" /></td> 
        </tr> 
      </tbody>  
    </table>
```

1)Here the rows can be automatically generated by the thymeleaf (th:each) object
2) i need to fetch all the `<td> <input>` values that has been through the jQuery. 
Only the **input** **values** in the *tbody* section has to be saved. Please guide me to achieve this.

Comment: There is no `_datas` attribute in the `tbody` section!!!?? Please clarify your question.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan sir, I just tried to use the italic font for the _datas in the tbody section has to be saved_. Please refer to the above table and values should be listed directly from the table using the thymeleaf object mbe from manualbillentry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accomplished a similar thing using [Tabledit.js](https://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/).

Download and include the same in your view file:

```
<script th:src="@{[your_path]/jquery.tabledit.js}"></script>
```

Then you provide a script as below to carry out your task:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#manualtable').Tabledit({
    url: "updateTableAtt", 
    columns: {
        //identifier is used as a unique id for passing your id for db operation
        identifier: [2, 'flatid'],

        //make value to be editable here, if you dont want user to edit some fields, comment out or delete those fields from below list.
        editable: [[0, 'powercharge'], [1, 'watercharge'], [2, 'flatid']]
    }
});
</script>
```

Add/Modify/Remove the `editable` list of attributes accordingly.

Using above script, you can get your values in controller using `@RequestParam`.

Comment: @Anjjaykarthick If the answer has helped you, please do mark it as *Accepted*.

Comment: sir, I just solved my issue by using this 
`value: $(tr).find("td:eq(3) input[type='text']").val()` and i completed by fetching this values through the jQuery and taking the values to the controller and saving it to the DB. **Thank you so much for your answer sir and i assure that i ll take a look on your post about the Inline table editor**